# No water coming from water supply line to icemaker

Tags: plumbing, ice-maker

I have a cold water shutoff valve going to icemaker. It is connected by vinyl tubing. That end had a a brass insert, sleeve, and nut on it. If I tighten it enough to stop water from dripping, I don't get any water coming from hose. What is causing this? 
[image: [1]]

Comment: Tightening which end stops the flow?

Comment: The compression nut

Comment: Sure.  But is it on the end in the photo, or at the icemaker end?

Comment: The end in photo

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a connection like this:

[image: 3/8 compression fitting assembly]

I've seen these fitting leak, but I've never seen them have no flow before.

Generally these compression fittings don't need to be on very tight, because it's the pressure of the sleeve against the fitting that keeps them from leaking. Usually they only take about one half to one full turn with a wrench after being hand tightened.

[image: compression fitting assembly]
[image: compression fitting tightened]

Things to check:

- Make sure the brass insert is not crushed or bent
- Make sure the sleeve is on straight, has no nicks or other damage, and seats well in the fitting
- Check the tube isn't folded over or crimped (if it is, cut it off a bit past the damaged part)
- The end of the insert shouldn't sit too deep within the valve. Generally the sleeve should be about centered over the insert.
- Check for blockage or dirt in the valve and on the edge of the fitting where the sleeve sits

Comment: My sleeve looks bigger than one in picture, but otherwise looks the same. I will check again on fitting tomorrow.

Comment: I pushed tubing tight against inside of shutoff valve. Would this cause a problem?

Comment: @dwhorne If the tubing is tight against the inside of the valve, when you tighten the compression nut it's going to push it even tighter. If the inside of the valve has a flat surface and is blocking the end of the tube, that means no water. I'd definitely guess that's the problem, and as I said the seat should be around the center of the insert. There should be enough space that the end of the tube is unobstructed so water can get into it when the nut is tightened.

Comment: I've checked it and there is water coming through tube I couldn't tell until I cut into tube. I've redone end and checking some other things on it now.

Comment: I had a kink in the line. Once that was removed, it flowed normally.